# In mapping, calling the result function is showing error

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract

```
contract mapping2{
  mapping(uint=>string[]) public data;
           
  function insert(uint roll,string memory name) public returns(string memory) {
    data[roll].push(name);
  }

  function result(uint _roll) public view returns(string memory) {
    return data[_roll];
  }
}
```

My error:

```sh
Return argument type string[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

`data[_roll]` is of type `string[]` according to the mapping definition. The function however is returning `returns(string memory)`, which is a different type (`string` != `string[]`).

So, you can write it like this:

```
  function result(uint _roll) public view returns(string[] memory) {
    return data[_roll];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning an array n the function. That is where the error is coming from.

```
function insert(uint roll,string memory name) public returns(string memory) {
    data[roll].push(name);
  }
```

should be

```
function insert(uint roll,string memory name) public returns(string[] memory) {
    data[roll].push(name);
  }
```

> returns(string[] memory) is not the same as
> returns(string memory)